# Meaning of divergence message?

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I am using the command `SMTNewtonIteration[]` to solve a boundary value problem in AceFEM and get the following error message:

[image]

[image]

What does this message mean exactly? Am I dividing somewhere by zero which leads to infinity?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 2):

The SMTNewtonIteration[] command did not produce the "Global divergence" message. It was produced by SMTConvergence[....] commands that monitor Newton-Raphson iterations. It means what it says. The Newton-Raphson iterative algorithm did not converge. The reason for that is always problem dependent and thus up to the user to find out. It can be something wrong with your tangent matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have an idea where the problem lies, now. I am trying to solve an equation which includes a division by a degree of freedom. Maybe, the initial guesses for all degrees of freedom are set to zero automatically by the programme itself to perform Newton's method. Therefore, there is a division by zero in the first step which could be the reason for the error.